# Did any country criticize Saudi Arabia for resuming talks with the U.S. about a defense pact?

Tags: international, saudi-arabia

> Saudi Arabia has resumed talks with the US about forging closer
> defense ties after a pause following the start of the Israel-Hamas war
> in early October, according to people familiar with the discussions.
> Discussions took place in the town of Alula in northwestern Saudi
> Arabia between de-facto ruler Crown Prince Mohammed Bin Salman and US
> senators earlier this month, said the people, asking not to be
> identified due to the sensitivity of the matter. On the agenda was a
> revival of earlier negotiations about a defense pact that would also
> have included an historic tie-up between Saudi Arabia and Israel, they
> said.
>
> MBS, as the 38-year-old leader is known, still sees opportunities for
> greater US cooperation despite anger across the Arab world over the
> continuing strikes by Israel, a key US ally, on Hamas, and the deaths
> of Palestinians in Gaza, said two people with knowledge of his
> thinking. The US is also at the heart of simmering regional tensions
> following a deadly attack on American forces in Jordan, alongside
> other airstrikes.

https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2024-01-30/saudis-resume-us-defense-talks-after-pause-forced-by-hamas-war?leadSource=reddit_wall

Did any country criticize Saudi Arabia for resuming talks with the U.S. about a defense pact? I remember that the prince mentioned that Saudi Arabia decided to suspend the discussion prior to resuming it because it would be a bad look to have such a conversation with the U.S. considering what was happening in Israel a few months ago, but now they've decided to resume talks when the crisis is still ongoing. Did any country, especially Muslim-majority country, criticize Saudi Arabia for resuming talks?